# How to update existing rows and insert new rows using stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a form in C# and SQL Server. I'm using a DATAGRIDVIEW to add new rows and update existing rows using the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[APPROVE_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS]
    @SAMPLE_ID int,
    @ORDER_ID int,
    @TESTID int,
    @SAMPLE_STATUS int,
    @organism_id int,
    @Antibiotic_id int,
    @sensitivityId int
AS
    -- just try to UPDATE the row
   UPDATE [dbo].[LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS]
   SET [sample_id] = @sample_id,
       [order_id] = @order_id,
       [testid] = @testid,
       [sample_status] = @sample_status,
       [organism_id] = @organism_id,
       [Antibiotic_id] = @Antibiotic_id,
       [sensitivityId] = @sensitivityId
   WHERE order_id = @order_id
     AND TESTID = @TESTID

    -- check if update was unsuccessful --> row doesn't exist yet, so insert
   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
       INSERT INTO [dbo].[LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS]
           ([sample_id], [order_id], [testid], [sample_status], [organism_id], [Antibiotic_id], [sensitivityId])
       VALUES (@sample_id, @order_id, @testid, @sample_status, @organism_id, @Antibiotic_id, @sensitivityId)
```

The existing rows before have Id No which is primary key, the new inserted rows to GRIDVIEW still no Id No as the following image:

[image]

How to update the stored procedure to update existing rows and insert new rows to database?

Thank you in advance.

This is the code in save button:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvcultures.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    result.APPROVE_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS(Convert.ToInt32(txtsample.Text),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(txtTestId.Text),
                                         6,
                                         Convert.ToInt32(dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value),
                                         Convert.ToInt32(dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value));
}
```

Comment: Looks like your SP works? Are you asking how to get the new ID back to display?

Comment: Why would your filtering values `Order_Id` and `TESTID` be part of the update? Other than that it would seem to make sense. Presumably your `Order_Id` is an `identity` which you need to return from `scope_identity()`

Comment: @DaleK no its not working correct not inserting last 2 new rows I think I need to change this condition  IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 because its updated 2 rows ?

Comment: If `order_id` is a PK then you shouldn't need `and  TESTID=`...?

Comment: You shouldn't need to because the SP can only handle one row at a time, which will either be an insert or update, so the fact that 2 updates have already happened won't affect the 3rd time you call it.

Comment: @Stu because the order_id also unique and order_id can include multiple test id so i need to update selected test id in this order

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by dividing the transactions ,

I created 2 stored procedures one for insert and one for update :

```
    create proc [APPROVE_ADD_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS]
    
    @SAMPLE_ID int,
    @ORDER_ID int,
    @TESTID int,
    @SAMPLE_STATUS int,
    @organism_id int,
    @Antibiotic_id int,
    @sensitivityId int
    
    
    as 
    
        
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS]
               ([sample_id]
               ,[order_id]
               ,[testid]
               ,[sample_status]
               ,[organism_id]
               ,[Antibiotic_id]
               ,[sensitivityId])
            
         VALUES
               (@sample_id
               ,@order_id
               ,@testid
               ,@sample_status
               ,@organism_id
               ,@Antibiotic_id
               ,@sensitivityId)

------------------------------------------

create proc [APPROVE_UPDATE_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS]

@SAMPLE_ID int,
@ORDER_ID int,
@TESTID int,
@SAMPLE_STATUS int,
@organism_id int,
@Antibiotic_id int,
@sensitivityId int,
@cult_id int

as 

    -- just try to UPDATE the row
   UPDATE [dbo].[LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS]
   SET [sample_id] = @sample_id
   ,[order_id] = @order_id
   ,[testid] = @testid
   ,[sample_status] = @sample_status
   ,[organism_id] = @organism_id
   ,[Antibiotic_id] = @Antibiotic_id
   ,[sensitivityId] = @sensitivityId
   
   WHERE order_id = @order_id
   and   TESTID = @TESTID
   and   cult_id  = @cult_id
```

Also if i want to delete rows from DATAGRIDVIEWS

I created datagridview delete checkbox and populated it :

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkboxdelete = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
  dgvcultures.Columns.Insert(0, checkboxdelete);
                checkboxdelete.HeaderText = "Delete";
                checkboxdelete.Name = "delete";
```

Finally in the save button I deleted checked rows and

insert new rows and update updated rows by using this code :

```
 // delete checked rows 
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvcultures.Rows)
                {
                    
                    bool status = (bool)row.Cells[0].FormattedValue;
                    if (status)
                    {
                        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS where order_id = '" + txtOrder.Text  + "' and cult_id = '" + row.Cells[7].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                }

                // insert new inserted rows 
                for (int i = 0; i < dgvcultures.Rows.Count ; i++)
                {
                    string idNo = dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(idNo) || idNo == null || idNo == DBNull.Value.ToString())
                    {
                        result.APPROVE_ADD_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS(Convert.ToInt32(txtsample.Text),
                        Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text),
                        Convert.ToInt32(txtTestId.Text),
                        6,
                        Convert.ToInt32(dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value),
                        Convert.ToInt32(dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value),
                        Convert.ToInt32(dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value));
                    }

                    // update rows
                    else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(idNo) || idNo != null || idNo != DBNull.Value.ToString())
                    {
                        result.APPROVE_UPDATE_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS(Convert.ToInt32(txtsample.Text),
                                                         Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text),
                                                         Convert.ToInt32(txtTestId.Text),
                                                         6,
                                                         Convert.ToInt32(dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value),
                                                         Convert.ToInt32(dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value),
                                                         Convert.ToInt32(dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value),
                                                         Convert.ToInt32(dgvcultures.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value));
                    }

                

            }
```